# Can't enter UTF-8 characters even though I have switched character encoding of terminal to UTF-8

Tags: c

I have changed my terminal encoding to UTF-8 using `intl.cpl` and changed system locale to UTF-8. However, I still cannot enter UTF-8 characters such as `å`. If I enter `chcp` then the output is:

```
Active code page: 65001
```

which indicates UTF-8 is "activated".

Then, why doesn't this code work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char myChar;

    printf("Enter the letter å: ");
    scanf("%c", &myChar);
    printf("Entered letter: %c", myChar);

    return 0;
}
```

Input is `å`.

Output is:

```
Enter the letter å: å
Entered letter:
```

Why does this happen? It is really frustrating and I would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The default locale of a C program is C. Switch locale to user locale that you set.

`å` in UTF-8 takes *two* bytes. It will not fit into one `char`. Use wide characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wchar_t myChar;
    printf("Enter the letter å: ");
    scanf("%lc", &myChar);
    printf("Entered letter: %lc", myChar);
}
```

Comment: UTF-8 is variant-width encoding, so one should not really use any specific type to represent "a character". Some take 1 bytes, some take 2, 3, or 4 bytes. Moreover, some "characters" (grapheme clusters) take multiple code points, so they can take arbitrary number of bytes depending on Unicode standard supported. Like country flag emoji.

Comment: The 2nd reason given (`uft8` chars do not fit in `char`) is correct, tho the solution isn't (see @yeputons comment). But the first is not. C has not his say in encoding here. Its job is just to copy whatever it is supposed to print, to the output device, without caring about what the output device with do with it (and remember that C&unix date back from the time when the output device was an actual line printer). It is up to the output device to do whatever it wants with the bytes it receives.

Comment: The default locale impact the way numbers or dates are formatted, for example. But not what the output device (here a terminal emulator) does with it.

Comment: With this code I get this output: Enter the letter Ã¥: å
Entered letter:

Comment: @chrslg It changes how the standard library converts the input bytes into wchar_t datatype. So you can set your terminal to EBCDIC and standard C library when `scanf` reading character will convert EBCDIC to utf-32 (utf-16 for windows) and save in wchar_t. LC_CTYPE configures conversion `mbtowc` and `wctomb` and configures how the C standard library deals with what comes from and to terminal or other input.

Comment: `With this code I get this output: Enter the letter Ã¥: å Entered letter` I am sorry, but I know nothing about windows, which I believe you are working on - you did not specify what terminal, compiler, operating system, etc. you are using  - please do specify it in your question. I guess with windows, someone else would have to help you.

Comment: Yes, it does that too. And many other things. But for low level functions such as `scanf` and `printf` that the OP is using, it does nothing. So my point is, "it is not because the OP forgot to set the locale that printf doesn't print utf". Those functions are completely agnostic to encoding. Scanf just read any bytes that comes from stdin. Printf just pass them along to stdout. What the devices that are on the other ends of those stdin and stdout lines (or more realisticly the software that emulate such devices) do, is up to them.

Comment: I disagree. `scanf` nor `printf` do not pass bytes "along". At least on glibc, both scanf and printf basically come with full iconv implementation. [Here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L1035) printf converts wide character to multibyte using mbsrtowcs. [Here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L1173) printf converts wide character to multibyte character using wcsrtombs. It is untrue that printf and scanf pass characters along - they do the conversions for the output streams.

Comment: Additionally, in libio, a wide stream and narrow stream are loaded with proper iconv conversion functions. I would have to find it. This all is documented in https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams-and-I18N.html : `What happens instead is that the bytes read from or written to the underlying media are first converted into the internal encoding chosen by the implementation for wchar_t. The external encoding is determined by the LC_CTYPE [...]`. I may be there is a misunderstanding. Locale affects the C implementation. To use wchar_t, you should set locale.

Comment: Unfortunately, although `wchar_t` accommodates the character 'å' in most configurations of most C implementations you're likely to meet, `wchar_t` is not necessarily sufficient for *arbitrary* Unicode characters.  It is not guaranteed to be any wider than `char`, and there have historically been implementations where it isn't.  It is 16 bits wide in many implementations, which is insufficient for representing characters outside the BMP in a single `wchar_t`.

Comment: @AlexanderJonsson  "With this code I get this output" On Windows you need to jump through a few additional hoops, but they are all described (many times) right on this site. Use the search function.

Comment: @chrslg Have you tried to run this program with LANG set to C? What result did you get?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this happen?

Because in UTF-8, `å` is encoded as a multi-byte sequence.  You are reading and echoing only the first byte.  Multi-byte characters cannot be stored in or represented by individual `char`s.  That's pretty much a definition of "multi-byte".

A key thing going on here is some mismatched terminology.  For the most part, where the C language specification and standard library documentation use the term "character", unqualified, they mean a `char`-sized binary number.  That is, roughly speaking, one byte.

But where the Unicode specifications say "character", unqualified, they generally mean *abstract* character.  You can't touch characters in this sense.  What you can touch is rather what Unicode would call *encoded characters*, which represent the Unicode *character codes* of abstract characters via sequences of *code units* according to a particular *encoding form*.  UTF-8 is a Unicode encoding form featuring variable-length code sequences made up of 8-bit code units.

When you say you want to input a "Unicode character", what you seem to mean is that you want to input one complete code sequence, and with UTF-8 that may be anywhere from one to four bytes (and with UTF-16, it could be either one or two 16-bit units).  The most transparent way to do that in C is to input into and output from a C string.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char mb_char[5];

    printf("Enter the letter å: ");
    scanf("%4s", &mb_char);
    printf("Entered letter: %s", mb_char);

    return 0;
}
```

Do note, however, that although that will definitely read at least one UTF-8-encoded character, it might read more than one (but possibly less than a full two) if the user inputs more than one.

Overall, if you can afford to ignore the specific encoding form (but assume that it uses one-byte code units) then just treating it all as strings is a fine strategy. This would be the case if all you need to do is read, store, and echo back character data as fed to the program.

On the other hand, if you need to do anything that is encoding-aware, or if you want to more cleanly handle encodings with different-sized code units, or do various other Unicode-aware activities, then you probably should engage a library designed to handle that.  [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/) is a popular and well-supported one, for example, and I have personally had good success with it.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not possible for love or money** to read UTF-8 characters from Windows terminal using Microsoft C runtime library aka `msvcrt`. You are trying to do it wrong, which is detailed in other answers, but even when you do it right, i.e. in a manner that works on every other system, it still does not work on Windows using `msvcrt`.

Your options are:

- use some other runtime, e.g. [`cygwin` or `ucrt`](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/)
- use UTF-16 input

**Late edit**: the above is no longer true. UTF-8 input works out of the box using Windows 11 22621.2428, MSVC 19.32.31332.0, and Windows terminal 1.18.2822. This saga is finally over.